# Jquery delete css class from style section

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have many classes in my style section. How can I remove a class from the styles section using jquery/javascript? For example:

```
<style id="myStyle"> 
.myClass { color: red);
.myClassSecond { color: black};
</style>

$('.myButton').click(function(){
//delete .myClass from style section
});
```

Comment: $('section').removeClass('myClass')

Comment: Sounds like an X/Y problem - what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Seems like it would be easier to just remove the class from all the elements that have it

Comment: .removeClass dont delete class from style section.

Comment: You can target the entire style element, `$('#myStyle')` and then rewrite the styles and update it with `$('#myStyle').html(newStyles)`.

Answer (score 0):

The example below will remove a class from any element given. You wouldn't remove the css class from the styles section, you would just remove it from the element for which you do not want to class to be applied.

```
$(".myButton").click(function(){
    //Replace "elementUsingTheClass" with your element that has the class set
    $("elementUsingTheClass").removeClass("myClass");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I think it's better to just remove the class from the elements in the page,  if you truly want to remove the class from the stylesheet in memory, here's how you get it done (tested in Chrome).

```js
$('.myButton').click(function(){
//delete .myClass from style section
var stylesheets = document.styleSheets;
for (var sheet in stylesheets) {

var rules =  stylesheets[sheet].cssRules;
var found = false;
for (var rule in rules) {
  if (rules[rule].selectorText == ".myClass") {
  found = true;
  console.log("found");
  console.log("deleting rule");
  stylesheets[sheet].deleteRule(rules[rule]);
  }
}
// verify
if (found) {
found = false;
for (var rule in rules) {
  if (rules[rule].selectorText == ".myClass") {
  found = true;
  console.log("found again :(");
  
  }
}
}
console.log(found);
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style id="myStyle"> 
.myClass { color: black;background-color:red;);
.myClassSecond { color: black};
</style>
<button class="myClass myButton">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it by reading the text of your style, like

```
var styleContent = document.getElementById("myStyle").innerText;
```

and then get the rows, like this:

```
var sourceRows = styleContent.split("\n");
```

and then copy the rows you want to keep:

```
var destinationRows = [];
for (var index in sourceRows) {
    if (sourceRows[index].indexOf(".myClass") < 0)
        destinationRows.push(sourceRows[index]);
}
```

and then put it back to your style:

```
document.getElementById("myStyle").innerText = destinationRows.join("\n");
```

But beware of the potential problems:

- you might have styles you want remove outside this style tag
- you might have rules spanning in multiple rows, in that case this solution will not work per se, but it will be a good starting point